# Run code section, rather than line of code by ctrl+enter in RStudio

Tags: rstudio

This one feature used making my coding life convenient extremely.

In earlier version of RStudio (lost track, but should be installed at around mid-2016), if i have a code section like

```
a_data_frame %>%
  dplyr::mutate(col3 = col1 + col2) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(col3) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n = n()) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

and i put the cursor on anywhere of the first line, without selected anything, and hit ctrl + enter, then RStudio would sent the whole section into console.

In addition, when there are multiple line of comments, hit ctrl + enter will also jump over all these lines, and cursor active at the beginning of next line of code.

This feature is gone [?] when I installed the newest version of RStudio.

Would anyone let me know how to turn it on?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You probably installed a preview release of RStudio (this feature is not available yet in the released version). Version 1.0 and newer of RStudio has this feature. You can get the 1.0 preview here; it will be released soon:

https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/

To turn it on, check *Execute all lines in a statement* in Options -> Code:

[image]

Comment: As you explained, I recalled that I should installed the preview release of RStudio for trying out rbookdown. I was then so used to this feature. Thanks a lot for your great work.